# floats always get rounded up

Tags: sql

i have a table with column of type Float(10) called tpm, but when i do `Insert INTO table_name(...,tpm) VALUES (...,59.9)`, the entry is 60 instead of 59.9! What am i doing wrong?
It's not a matter of display the value is definetly 60 ( i tried select with `WHERE tpm < 60` and got no results)

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: `float` is inexact by nature. If you want a finite, precise number use `decimal(...)`.